# How to set table's row height?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I Word document i have a two tables. I fill it with data using `OpenXML`:

```
var firstTable = (mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Table>().ToList())[1];
var firstTableRows = firstTable.ChildElements.OfType<TableRow>().ToArray();
var firstTableRowСells = firstTableRows[0].ChildElements.OfType<TableCell>().ToArray();

var secondTable = (mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Table>().ToList())[2];
var secondTableRows = secondTable.ChildElements.OfType<TableRow>().ToArray();
var secondTableRowСells = secondTableRows[0].ChildElements.OfType<TableCell>().ToArray();

firstTableRowСells[0].ChildElements.First<Paragraph>().ChildElements.First<Run>().ChildElements.First<Text>().Text = firstString;

secondTableRowСells[0].ChildElements.First<Paragraph>().ChildElements.First<Run>().ChildElements.First<Text>().Text = secondString;
```

Strings what i put into tables may have a different length so it's causes the that rows have a different height. But i want that same rows in tables have a same height. It's mean: if `firstString.Lenght>secondString.Lenght` i want set row's height in secondTable like row's height in firstTable.
And if `secondString.Lenght>firstString.Lenght` i want set row's height in firstTable like row's height in secondTable.

It's possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(
    new TableRowProperties(
        new TableRowHeight() {Val = Convert.toUInt32("20")}));
```

Comment: `TableRowHeight` not sets real row's height. I solve my problem using `Break()` in lower rows.

Comment: That is not the correct solution, but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: What unit is the TableRowHeight in? Is there some link between this number and the font size?